# Passing PostgreSQL psql error messages to unix shell variables

Tags: postgresql, output, ksh, psql

I am calling PostgreSQL function from Unix shell script.

Can anyone tell me how do i capture PostgreSQL error messages returned from the function in unix shell variables?

I used the below method but not able to

```
#!/bin/ksh

function crt_views
{
#Call the POSTGRE pkg which created dynamic views

echo "Calling POSTGRE function FN_CRT_ACTNET_VWS..." >> $LOGFILENAME
pg_msg=`psql --echo-all -U<uname> << EOF
set client_min_messages='NOTICE';
SELECT FUNC_CRT_VWS();
EOF`

}


crt_views
echo "PRINTING - $pg_msg"
```

In output I'm not seeing the errors returned from the PostgreSQL function. Please help

Comment: The accepted short version of the name is Postgres, not POSTGRE

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect *stderr* to *stdout*, since *backtick* ing something will get you only *stdout*.

This is because output that is both from `RAISE NOTICE` and `RAISE EXCEPTION` (among other things) is printed to *stderr* by *psql*.

**Note:** I also switched from using *backtick* ing to *dollar-paren* style execution. Using the *backtick*, redirecting *stderr* in this way doesn't work. (My testing was under *sh* instead of *ksh*, but in this case the behavior should be similar, I suspect.)

Also, `set -e` will fail on error, which may be desireable (depending on your needs).

So, that leads to something like this:

```
#!/bin/ksh

set -e

function crt_views
{
#Call the Postgres pkg which created dynamic views

echo "Calling Postgres function FN_CRT_ACTNET_VWS..." >> $LOGFILENAME
pg_msg=$(psql --echo-all -U<uname> << EOF
set client_min_messages='NOTICE';
SELECT FUNC_CRT_VWS();
EOF
2>&1)

}


crt_views
echo "PRINTING - $pg_msg"
```